# Unable to match on first column name after parsing CSV document

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on CSV import where I take a file (with headings as the first row) and parse the document into `DataTable` structure.

When I try to organise the data into a collection for some reason (unknown to me), my state machine fails to match on the very first column heading. It should be fairly straight forward, no magic involved.

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
        {
            switch(col.ColumnName)
            {
                default:
                // debug: Exceptions.LogException(new Exception(" csv {ColumnName:'" + col.ColumnName + "',Length:" + col.ColumnName.Length + ",Test:" + string.Equals(col.ColumnName, "Name") + "}"));
                break;

                case "Name":
                // doesn't get picked up
                break:
```

My debug line(s) return the following: `csv {ColumnName:'Name',Length:5,Test:False}`

Interestingly enough, if I add a dummy column to the file in front of `Name` column then my `case: "Name"` works fine.

Any ideas what could be causing an issue like that?

#### Great comments and suggestions

1. Reproducible code example - was going to make one today but it looks like we have a different problem
2. Leading/trailing spaces - checked for those before posting
3. `Name` being reserved - tried a different column name didn't make a difference
4. Weird characters - checked CSV in Notepad, Sublime (fancy Notepad) before posting for strange characters. But after `JAZ` suggested to check the length s/he was right on the money (see above).

[image: Small screenshot of CSV from Notepad which demonstrates there are nothing weird (or is there) about the Name column]

#### Pursuing the issue of weird characters

So far it doesn't seem to be any of the usual suspects: space, tab, newline, carriage return (or combination of both). But one thing is for sure it's at the begging of the string as suggested by debugging log.

```
sb.Append("{Col:'" + col.ColumnName.Substring(0, 3) + "',Len:" + col.ColumnName.Length + "}");
```

Returning `{Col:'vN',Len:6}` where first column is `vName`.

#### Culprit/Solution

Finally found the culprit `U+FEFF` aka `BYTE ORDER MARK` character which appears at the start of text stream (but can also appear in the middle `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`) and indicates the type of encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, etc).

Found by converting a string of characters into Unicode as follows:

```
col.ColumnName.Select(t => string.Format("U+{0:X4}", (ushort)t)).ToList()
```

Producing the following output for `vName` string:

- U+FEFF = [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
- U+0076 = v
- U+004E = N
- U+0061 = a
- U+006D = m
- U+0065 = e

#### Handy to know

Just wanted to share that you can quickly check the type of encoding and line break used by opening the file in Notepad. Would have been handy to know this when I was posting my question. Below are three different CSV files which use a different encoding.

[image: Notepad encoding and line break types]

Comment: Weird syntax to start a switch-case statement with the `default`

Comment: Give us a runnable example

Comment: @Cid doesn't make a difference even if I start with a list of ``case`` statements and ``default`` at the end. Same issue.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I will have to try this with a .Net fiddler which won't happen until next Monday, sorry.

Comment: Probably a line feed or some weird character in the data - What is the length of the string when it fails?  That would tell you if there are too many chars.Start with the CSV data and check it in a real editor, not Excel, see if there is something in the data

Comment: I'd also be interested to see what happens when you use a name other than "Name", since "Name" is a reserved word in many contexts.

Comment: You need to create the smallest reproducible code example for us to help you further. Chances are you might find the issue while creating the sample.

Comment: @Duston sorry already tried changing the ``Name`` to something else like ``tName`` thinking the same thing as you suggested. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: @JAZ while I haven't checked the length of the string. But as you can see it printed exactly. And, of course, the very first thing I did is check it in notepad to make sure there was nothing funny with my csv.

Comment: @JAZ you're right on the money with the length thing. ``Name`` should have a length of 4 but I am getting 5. Now I will try to figure this weird character that is sneaking its way into the string. Could post your suggestion an answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a line feed or some weird character in the data - What is the length of the string when it fails? That would tell you if there are too many chars.

Start with the CSV data and check it in a real editor, not Excel, see if there is something in the data.

Use Notepad++ and change the encoding of the text file to see the extra characters. Don't think Windows Notepad will show them.